# Laravel 5 - Eloquent - Paginate results

Tags: php, pagination, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5 for my project and I have this function to paginate the results:

```
return $query->approvate()->with( 'voti' )->get()->sortBy( function ( $sort )
{
    return $sort->voti->count();
}, 0, true );
```

I have tried to use `paginate()` but I need the results of the collection to be ordered before the pagination.

In Laravel 4 there was this method that has been removed in Laravel 5:

```
$paginator = Paginator::make($items, $totalItems, $perPage);
```

How can I paginate the results in L5 after the ordering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel has no way of paginating a collection, but I wrote a helper so you can still do this.

Try this code:

```
<?php
namespace Helpers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class Paginator extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {

private $pageNr;
private $perPage;
private $all;

public function paginate($perPage)
{
    $this->perPage = (int) $perPage;
    $this->pageNr = (int) $this->getCurrentPage();

    $this->all = $this->all();
    $this->items = array_slice($this->all(), $this->getCurrentPage()*$perPage-$perPage, $this->perPage);
    return $this;
}

public function getCurrentPage()
{
    $input = Input::get('page');
    if($input==null)
        return 1;
    return $input;
}

public function getLastPage()
{
    return(intval(ceil(count($this->all)/$this->perPage)));
}

public function getUrl($page)
{
    return url('zoeken?page='.$page);
}

}
```

You might need to change the getUrl function.

Usage:

```
$paginator = new \Helpers\Paginator(Collection $col);
$paginator->paginate(int $x);
```

Comment: Thanks, but how should I use it?

Comment: Make a helpers folder, make a new class with the code I just sent to you, edit your composer.json so that it autoloads the folder and check out the usage sample in my edit.

Comment: Great! And what about showing the page number? I tried $paginator->render() as I usually do but it do not work

Comment: You don't need the render here because you already have the collection. If you need to use the data in your view, Do `$items = $paginator->paginate(20);` And pass $items to your view.

Comment: Ok, and how can I create the page number for the navigation?

Comment: `$items->getCurrentPage()` returns the page number.

Comment: OK thanks! There is also a way to get something like the default pagination implamentation to get all the pages numbers with links? exactly someting like $items->render()

Comment: You'd only need getUrl for that. But if you want the render function, you could probably implement that yourself, just edit the helper! :) If I helped you, please tag this as the answer.