# Getting all objects from hasMany relation and paginate

Tags: php, pagination, laravel-5, relationship

In my Laravel application, I have a category listing page. When the user clicks on a certain subcategory, I'd like to list all the products and use pagination on that result. I'm already listing all the products related to that subcategory, for now, with the help of a subcategory ID:

```
public function subcategoryListing($slug){
    $products = Subcategory::find($idofSubcat)->products;
    return view('pages.subcategorylisting')
        ->with(array(
            'products' => $products,
        ));
}
```

There are three classes involved in this structure: **Category**, **Subcategory** and **Products**. They were declared as follows:

**Category**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;
use App\Subcategory;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'category';

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function subCategory(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Subcategory', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

**Subcategory**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Subcategory extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'subcategory';

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Products');
    }
}
```

**Products**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Products extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'products';
}
```

For each model class I have one table, with this structure:

```
Category
- id
- category_name

SubCategory
- id
- category_id
- subcategory_name

Products
- id
- subcategory_id
- product_title
- description
- price
```

What I want is to paginate the results retrieved from the query in my page. Is there any better way to fetch the `products` associated to the `subcategory` and paginate them?

Comment: kindly refer this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30095205/laravel-5-eloquent-paginate-results

Comment: Hey @Sid, what is the content of your `$slug` variable? Also that `$idofSubcat` variable you're using when calling `find` method doesn't seem to have being initialized.

Comment: Hey! Have my answer below ever helped you? If so, please accept it as the correct one. Doing that you may help others seeking a solution for a similar problem.

Answer (score 6):

In Eloquent (Laravel's ORM) when you call a relation as a property (`$subCategory->products`), it returns the related object or a collection of objects depending on the relation type (belongs to, has many, ...). Instead, if you call it as a function (`$subCategory->products()`), you get a `QueryBuilder` instance.

Refer to http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations, under section **Relationship Methods Vs. Dynamic Properties** for more details on that.

Anyway, using the relationship method, you can call `paginate()` for your collection. Then, with that in mind, you can change your code slightly to get what you want:

```
public function subcategoryListing($slug) {

    // I'm supposing here that in somewhere before 
    // run the query, you set the value to $idofSubcat 
    // variable

    $products = Subcategory::find($idofSubcat)->products()->paginate();
    return view('pages.subcategorylisting')
        ->with(array(
            'products' => $products,
        ));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think, that create two categories table not so correctly, it will be better to use next:

table categories

```
id    category_name   parent_id(nullable)
```

and Products

```
 id          category_id        product_title      description     price
```

It's more usefull, you can remove one Subcategory model and do all in Category.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'category';

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function subCategory(){

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'categories', 'id', 'parent_id');
    }

    public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Products');
    }
}
```

and products model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Products extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'products';

    public function category() {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Category')
    }


}
```

then, you can get the query result

```
public function subcategoryListing($slug){
        $products = Category::find($idofSubcat)->products;
        return view('pages.subcategorylisting')
            ->withProducts($products); // it's a magic)) 
}
```

But, existing one not pretty thing. Do you really sure, that products will be only in one category?)

Comment: basically, i have categories and subcategory, and product belongs to subcategory and different product goes to different subcategory and there will be multiple categories as well. And above solution didn't work in my case

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't really understand some of your initial function:

```
// $slug is not being used anywhere within the function
public function subcategoryListing($slug){

    // $idOfSubcat isn't passed to this function so will throw an error
    $products = Subcategory::find($idofSubcat)->products;

    return view('pages.subcategorylisting')
        ->with(array(
            'products' => $products,
        ));
}
```

If all you're trying to do is paginate the `Products` that belong to a specific `subcategory_id`, given you have the `subcategory_id` then the following code will work:

```
$products = Product::where('subcategory_id', $idofSubcat)->paginate();
```

Then you can return this paginated collection to your view as you're already doing:

```
return view('pages.subcategorylisting')
    ->with(compact('products'));
```

Comment: what's your reason to user compact() ?

Comment: @Pedrammarandi `compact('products')` gives the same result as `[ 'products' => $products, ]`. Anyway, I think the second form (declare the array directly) is better in terms of performance since it doesn't have to call a function.

Comment: You don't need to use ```compact```, I simply provided it as an alternative that I feel reads a little more naturally. It does take fractionally more resources than explicitly defining the array - but based on your question, I can't see this ever becoming a bottleneck.